# custom image fader

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-animate

Im trying to make an image fader gallery that cycles through a number of images, and then repeats.  I have successfully written the part where it fades through the images, but I can't figure out how to make it repeat.  The current code I'm using just loads infinitely, I think because I've somehow created an infinite loop but I'm not sure how or how to get around it.

jQuery

```
//create array with the images id tags
var img_arr = [
            '#img1',
            '#img2',
            '#img3'
        ]
        var i = 0;
        arr_length = img_arr.length;
        gal_repeat = img_arr.length - 1;
        $(document).ready(function img_gallery() {
            //loop through the fade animation until the end of the array
            for (i = 0; i < arr_length; i++) {
                $(img_arr[i])
                    .animate(
                        { opacity: '1.0' }, 2000
                    );
                $('.img').delay(1000).animate({opacity: 0.0}, 2000);
                //THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS.  if I comment out this 'if' 
                //statement, the gallery works fine but doesn't repeat
                if (i == gal_repeat) {
                    i = 0;
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: the infinite loop is because your setting the value of i back to 0 inside the for loop, and the if statement will always be hit on the last run of the loop, hence infinite loop. I would suggest pursuing a different method of establishing the end of the images, other than the loop counter variable

Comment: I know it creates an infinite loop, but shouldn't it not loop back to the beginning until all the images have been faded through with the delay? I guess my question is really trying to understand why it is causing the page to crash

Comment: you loop has no until!?, there is nowhere in that loop that it stops, based on the one principle of i, which you keep resetting to zero as soon as i gets to its last iteration. You need to rethink you logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setInterval for repetitive stuff:

```
//create array with the images id tags
var images = ['#img1', '#img2', '#img3'];
numberOfImages = images.length;

$(document).ready(function() {

    var num = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        num = (num + 1) % numberOfImages;

        $(images[num]).animate({
            opacity: '1.0'
        }, 2000);

        $('.img').delay(1000).animate({
            opacity: 0.0
        }, 2000);

    }, 5000);
});
```